# Run single PS script from Release definition without pulling down entire project

Tags: tfs, tfvc, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my release definition, I want to run a single PS script which lives in source control (TFVC in my case). I don't see a way to do this without TFS pulling down the entire source tree containing the one script on the agent machine. I currently have an unversioned copy of the script out on the agent machine, and I reference its absolute path from the release definition. This works, but I'm not guaranteed the latest version of this script to be run at release time.

Comment: Which version control, Git or TFVC?

Comment: TFVC. Thanks! I'll amend my question.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two way to do it:

1. define a mapping that picks only what you need -- you can define a mapping up to a single file, e.g. cloak `$/` and map `$/path_to_my_file`
2. use a dummy build that collects the file you need and save them as artifacts,  I explained this technique in http://blog.casavian.eu/2017/03/04/mixing-tfvc-and-git/

Comment: How can I un-cloak a folder in Tfs2017 Build Mappings? There are only the Types "Map" and "Cloak" available. Can I use the type "Map" for un-cloaking?

Comment: That is what I meant "Map" (sorry, had no UI at hand while answering)

Comment: No problem, thanks for the quick reply and your great blog entry.